# How can I repair laminate floor boards with damaged edges?

Tags: repair, flooring, laminate-floor

I noticed that two panels of my laminate floor board have not joined well: there is a small gap between them. Now, it seems that constant wear is damaging the edges of the board.

[image]

Is there any way to repair this? Basically I would like to seal the gap to stop the chipboard edges from getting more damaged.

Potentially I was thinking of using some kind of glue/sealer/enamel that I could fill into the gap. (I thought to use a Stanley blade to cut a constant V into the edge, then fill.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't be a true seal, but if it's not in a high-traffic area, you might be able to trim any flaking bits and then de-emphasize the gap left with [wax putty](http://www.moffitt-smith.com/Products/Mohawk-Fil-Stik-Wax-Putty-Stick---Standard-Colors__M230-.aspx).

I wouldn't attempt to cut the board out; trying to get a new board back in is likely be more difficult to get looking correct, as you potentially have 4 edges to contend with; you can sometimes deal with it if it's true tongue-and-groove, but the click-lock's much more difficult to get down correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very thin blade like that on a multi-tool to cut out the damaged piece, then drop in a replacement piece to fit, gluing it down solidly underneath.